# Reduce the size of .air file

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am using Flex Builder 3. Even for a small project, my exported .air file's size is around 400k. Is it because of all the Flex libraries being compiled into my application. I wanted to know if it is possible to remove the libraries that I don't use.

What are libraries like "qtp.swc" and the "automation" libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything gets included in the Air package which is why it's big.  QTC and Automation libraries are *not* needed and I don't think they actually get added in when you run a release build (as you should).